# BC 17 Installation in a Docker Environment

Tags: docker, dynamics-business-central

Prior to BC17 I would download the appropriate image file and use the new-navContainer command to create a BC Container.   I have read that the process is different for BC17. The articles I've found only saying the process is changing but not what the new process is.

Does anybody know the new way to create a BC17 Docker container?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch from NavContainerHelper to BcContainerHelper.

1. Remove all existing containers created with NavContainerHelper:

   ```
   Get-NavContainer | Remove-NavContainer
   ```
2. Remove NavContainerHelper:

   ```
   Get-InstalledModule "navcontainerhelper" -AllVersions | Uninstall-Module
   ```
3. Install BcContainerHelper

   ```
   Install-Module BcContainerHelper -force
   ```
4. Recreate your containers using `New-BcContainer`.

With the switch to BcContainerHelper you will notice that a new folder `C:\bcartifacts.cache` will appear on your system. This folder is used to cache the artifacts needed to create an image for a specific version of Business Central.

If you don't have that much space on your C drive, you can change the location of the cache by editing the properties of the `$bcContainerHelperConfig` variable.

For more information you can check out [this blog post](https://freddysblog.com/2020/10/10/bccontainerhelper-configuration/).